# set all nodes as selected onload in jstree jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jstree

I am using jstree jquery.I want to set all nodes selected onload dynamically.

Or how can i set checked="true or false" just like state="open or close" in xml file..

Can any1 help...

Answer (score 8):

To make all nodes checked when running [`jstree`](http://www.jstree.com/) with [`checkbox`](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox) plugin, call `check_all()` on the tree control, or `check_node()` on top level node to check all nodes in a particular branch.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // select the whole jstree control
    $("#tree_control").jstree("check_all");
    // select a whole branch:
    $('#tree_control').jstree("check_node", "#top_level_node_id");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
$(".jstree li[role=treeitem]").each(function () {
     $(".jstree").jstree('select_node', this)
});
```

and for onload use this code

```
$(".jstree").jstree().on('loaded.jstree', function () {
    $(".jstree li[role=treeitem]").each(function () {
        $(".jstree").jstree('select_node', this)
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To open all children of a node simply call:

```
open_all('#selector-to-the-node');
```